# Create features (long vector) with scala

Tags: scala, vector, apache-spark

I have a Big `CSV` file (~2GB) that contains a parameter X that for each day has around 1000 record. 
What I want to do is transform this column to a set features (vectors) of length 1000 (one for each day). 
For example:

```
==> Day 1   Day P1
            1   1
            1   2
            1   5
            1   9
            1   .
            1   .
            1   .
            1   6 
==> Day 2   1   4
            2   1
            2   2
            2   5
            2   7
            2   .
            2   .
            2   .
            2   8
```

Will be transformed to:

```
d1 1 2 5 9 . . . 6
d2 4 1 2 5 . . . 8 
.
.
. 
dn
```

How can I do that in `Scala` ?
I know that there will be issue with the memory, I'll try to store the result on multiple steps.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
df_data.map(x => (x(1),x(3))).filter(x=> x._1== 1).zipWithIndex.map(x=> (x._1._1,(x._2,x._1._2))).groupByKey()
```

Now I get something like:

```
(1, (0,val1),(1,val2),(2,val3),...,(n,valn))
```

Comment: I tried to do that for one day  and then loop over all the others. 
 
    `df_data.map(x => (x(1),x(3))).filter(x=> x._1== "day_1").zipWithIndex.map(x=> (x._1._1,(x._2,x._1._2))).groupByKey()`

Now I get something like `(day1, (0,val1),(1,val2),(2,val3),...,(n,valn))`

Comment: Edit your question to show the code you're using, and explain why what you get isn't what you expect.